# C#: How to override functions in one class without multiple inheritance from different services

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, service

I have a service `ServiceA` inherited from `SoapHttpClientProtocol`.

Also, I have a class `ProcessingHelperClass`, that is inherited from `ServiceA` with some overriden functions and a couple of additional fields.

I have lots of `ServiceA` kind of services. And I need to create my `class` with overriden functions for everyone of them.

My question: Is there any way to create just one class with overriding functions and additional fields for different services so I don't have to create a new class for every service I include.

And If my question is very bad in sense of programming, I would be glad to learn why, as I'm a newbie

**UPD**: Pseudo code
Reference.cs (file with service proxy class)

```
public partial class ServiceA : SoapHttpClientProtocol
{
     public void Method1(){};
     public void Method2(){};
     //etc...

}
```

ProcessingHelperClass.cs

```
 public class ProcessingHelperClass: ServiceA, IDisposable
 {
     private XmlWriter _xmlWriter;
     public String StringA => xmlWriter == null? "" : _xmlWriter.Xml;
     ...
     protected override XmlWriter GetWriterForMessage(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientMessage message, int bufferSize)
     {
        var writer = base.GetWriterForMessage(message, bufferSize);
        _xmlWriterSpy = new XmlWriterSpy(writer);
        return _xmlWriterSpy;
     }
 }
```

Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ProcessingHelperClass client = new ProcessingHelperClass();
   client.Method1();
   Console.Writeline(client.StringA);
}
```

Comment: Could you post a pseudo-code, which does what you want?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance. You should implement what you want by adding an instance of the class with your implementing-methods as a *member* of your services. You won´t need derive from `SoapHttpClientProtocol` in this case because the actual methods are stored in another class.

Comment: Added pseudocode. Hope it helps. If anything wrong, please, let me know

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can inherit from only one class. This makes overriding methods from multiple classes in one class not a valid strategy. You can however, inherit from multiple interfaces. If you can inherit from multiple interfaces, you can implement these interfaces in one class.

```
public interface IServiceA
{
   bool IsVisible();
}
public interface IServiceB
{
   void SetValue();
}
public class SomeClass : IServiceA, IServiceB
{
   public bool IsVisible(){}
   public void SetValue(){}
}
```

The downside to this is, that you cannot re-use a previously implemented method because there are no previously implemented methods. This can be countered by implementing classes for each interface seperately, and then combining objects of these classes in one 'superclass';

```
public interface IServiceA
{
   bool IsVisible();
}
public interface IServiceB
{
   void SetValue();
}
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
   public bool IsVisible(){}
}
public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
   public void SetValue(){}
}
public class SomeClass : IServiceA, IServiceB
{
   private IServiceA _a;
   private IServiceB _b;

   public SomeClass(IServiceA a, IServiceB b)
   {
      _a = a;
      _b = b;
   }

   public bool IsVisible()
   {
     _a.IsVisible(); // if you want to re-use
   }
   public void SetValue()
   {
      // implement some logic here if you want to 'override'
   }
}
```